# select multiple nodes from multiple xml files in powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell

I'am new to Poweshell and have about 100 xml files with the same structure and I want to list two nodes from all of them in one list.

I have succeeded from one xml file but then I specify a specific path to the xml file, so somehow I need to do a loop through all the xml files in the folder ("C:\Users\mittm\Documents\ps).

```
$Path = "C:\Users\mittm\Documents\ps\myxml.xml"

$xml = New-Object -TypeName XML
$xml.Load($Path)

$Xml.catalog.book | Select-Object -Property title, author
```

Gives the result

```
title   author
-----   ------
Title 1 Author 1
```

But I want the result

```
title   author
-----   ------
Title 1 Author 1
Title 2 Author 2
Title 3 Author 3
```

xml-file 1

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Author 1</author>
      <title>Title 1</title>
      <price>44.95</price>   
   </book>
</catalog>
```

xml-file 2

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Author 2</author>
      <title>Title 2</title>
      <price>44.95</price>   
   </book>
</catalog>
```

And so on with about 100 xml-files. My real xml has more tags than my examples inside the book but I still want to select two but shortened it to save space.

Answer (score 0):

All you are missing is `Get-ChildItem` to query all the files (use `-Recurse` switch if you need to go into subfolders)

From there, by assigning the foreach to a variable, you should end up with the list containings all the results from all the xmls.

```
$AllXmls = Get-ChildItem -Path 'Path\to the xmls files' -Filter '*.xml' -File #-Recurse

$Output = foreach ($Path in $AllXmls.FullName) {
    $xml = New-Object -TypeName XML
    $xml.Load($Path)
    $Xml.catalog.book | Select-Object -Property title, author
}
```